# Fibration on arc-wise connected basis

Tags: general-topology, fibration

Let be $(E,B;\pi)$ a fibration, with $B$ a topological spaces arc-wise connected. I know that $\pi$ is necessarily surjective and that for each path between two points in $B$ exists a path between two point in the preimage of them. This implies that take two fiber its are homotopically equivalent.

Why?

Comment: And what is your question?